# formatting an integer output using ostream

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the equivalence of %2d using `cout << <<endl` format.  how can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The header `<iomanip>` contains the stream manipuator `setw`:

```
cout << setw(2) << myint << endl
```

You may also be interested in setfill:

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << myint << endl
```

will pad with a 0 instead of a space.

Answer (score 4):

You need [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/)

Comment: so I would do:
setw (2) fo %2d?

Comment: Yes. cout<<setw(2)<<value<<endl;